# using new google-api-client GoogleCredentials with old GData Contacts service

Tags: oauth-2.0, gdata, google-contacts-api, google-data-api, google-apps-marketplace

We have an application using Google Contacts with 2-legged OAuth 1.0 which works great but we want to migrate to OAuth 2.0. So far it looks like old GData libraries aren't playing nice with this OAuth 2.0 and 2-legged authorization. On the other hand new google-api-client libraries handles this gracefully but it doesn't provide Contacts API. So we wanted to use the new `GoogleCredentials` which are really simple to use with the old ContactsService but it the `Bearer` token is set to `null` in the request causing `java.lang.NullPointerException: No authentication header information`. Does anybody have an idea what may go wrong?

Anonymized test script can be found at https://gist.github.com/musketyr/9394815

Comment: The NPE is due to a bug that only affects certain user agents. You can work around it using the method I described here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286369/google-contacts-api-failing-to-refresh-access-token/26466985#26466985

Fixing that should allow you to get more information about the error being thrown.

Comment: can you post this as answer, so I can mark it as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NPE is due to a bug that only affects certain user agents. You can work around it using the method I described here: [Google Contacts API - failing to refresh access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286369/google-contacts-api-failing-to-refresh-access-token/26466985#26466985). Fixing that should allow you to get more information about the error being thrown.