# Google Contacts API - failing to refresh access token

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-contacts-api, google-data-api

We use Google Contacts API with OAuth2:

```
credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(new NetHttpTransport())
        .setJsonFactory(new JacksonFactory())
        .setClientSecrets(OAuth2ClientId(), OAuth2ClientSecret())
        .addRefreshListener(new CredentialRefreshListener() {...});

myService = new ContactsService("My-App");
myService.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
```

and quite regularly we receive '401 Unauthorized' response that the GData library can't handle.
AuthenticationException throws NPE when `WWW-Authenticate` header is missing.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: No authentication header information
        at com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException.initFromAuthHeader(AuthenticationException.java:96) ~[gdata-core-1.0-1.47.1.jar:na]
        at com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException.<init>(AuthenticationException.java:67) ~[gdata-core-1.0-1.47.1.jar:na]
        at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:608) ~[gdata-core-1.0-1.47.1.jar:na]
        at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:564) ~[gdata-core-1.0-1.47.1.jar:na]
        at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560) ~[gdata-core-1.0-1.47.1.jar:na]
        at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538) ~[gdata-core-1.0-1.47.1.jar:na]
        at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536) ~[gdata-core-1.0-1.47.1.jar:na]
        at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1135) ~[gdata-core-1.0-1.47.1.jar:1.47.1]
        at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1077) ~[gdata-core-1.0-1.47.1.jar:1.47.1]
        at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:676) ~[gdata-core-1.0-1.47.1.jar:1.47.1]
        at com.google.gdata.client.Service.query(Service.java:1237) ~[gdata-core-1.0-1.47.1.jar:1.47.1]
        at com.google.gdata.client.Service.query(Service.java:1178) ~[gdata-core-1.0-1.47.1.jar:1.47.1]
```

We managed to add a wrapper that would try token refreshing on this NPE. It helps but then there are still many cases when refreshing fails:

```
credential.refreshToken() == false
```

When we run `refreshToken()` in the debugger we see that `executeRefreshToken()` is executed without an exception but `tokenResponse==null` is returned. As a result `refreshToken()` returns `false` and no reason is passed to the listeners

```
try {
    TokenResponse tokenResponse = executeRefreshToken();
    if (tokenResponse != null) {
      setFromTokenResponse(tokenResponse);
      for (CredentialRefreshListener refreshListener : refreshListeners) {
        refreshListener.onTokenResponse(this, tokenResponse);
      }
      return true;
    }
  } catch (TokenResponseException e) {
    boolean statusCode4xx = 400 <= e.getStatusCode() && e.getStatusCode() < 500;
    // check if it is a normal error response
    if (e.getDetails() != null && statusCode4xx) {
      // We were unable to get a new access token (e.g. it may have been revoked), we must now
      // indicate that our current token is invalid.
      setAccessToken(null);
      setExpiresInSeconds(null);
    }
    for (CredentialRefreshListener refreshListener : refreshListeners) {
      refreshListener.onTokenErrorResponse(this, e.getDetails());
    }
    if (statusCode4xx) {
      throw e;
    }
  }
  return false;
```

Our tokens are always for multiple scopes: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.google.com/m8/feeds https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar https://mail.google.com/ https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks`

**Update:** We've successfully moved to People API and the new API is also used by our Unified API Contacts API https://docs.aurinko.io/article/25-contacts-api

Comment: To clarify, sometimes the refresh works but sometimes it doesn't? Once the refresh stops working, does it ever work again? AKA, is it a temporary state or a permanent one?

Comment: Ok, we've been experimenting more with this. The behavior seems a bit different for Contacts vs. Calendar&Tasks. It looks like for Calendar&Tasks credential.refreshToken() may fail without a reason but if you wait and try again it may actually refresh the token. For Contacts it's the NPE "No authentication header information" but then again if you try again in some cases it does end up refreshing the token and in other cases it just always fails.

Comment: I'm working on replicating the problem. I certainly see the NPE being thrown, but still working on getting the refresh to fail.

Comment: Eric I updated the question. I you want I could share with you a set of access/refresh tokens for which this happens quite regularly. I wonder if token refreshing is rate limited by Google because if we try more times to refresh we usually succeed eventually.

Comment: This may be a separate issue but I've also noticed that for Gmail/IMAP XOAUTH a newly refreshed token often is rejected by Gmail/IMAP. It feels like the refreshed token is not propagated fast enough to Gmail servers and they don't know about it yet when we try to use it. Again, we put some wrappers to wait a bit before using the token and that seems to help. So in general our token refreshing procedures now are wrapped into our code that handles NPE, retries and then waits and then retries again. Not very elegant.

Comment: executeRefreshToken method has this comment "successful response from the token server or null if it is not possible to refresh the access token". In our case 'null' is returned often but additional attempts would succeed. Do you know why it would be "not possible to refresh token"?

Comment: How often are you refreshing the token? Are there multiple threads each using the refresh token to generate access tokens? That could have an impact.

Comment: I think the token is refreshed hourly. Yes, there could be multiple threads refreshing it. We actually store 1-4 copies of the same multi-scope token and then 1-4 threads (calendar, contacts, email, tasks) are using its own copy and could be refreshing the token when it expires.

Comment: I refactored our code to use one shared GoogleCredential instead of 1-4 (one per each service thread). This way is probably more correct and should prevent parallel attempts to refresh the token (there is locking/synchronization in that method). Will have to monitor to see if this helps.

Comment: With Gmail/XOAUTH2 it's some other issue. The token is refreshed fine but the following IMAPS connection still fails: [ALERT] Invalid credentials (Failure)
        at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:715) ~[javax.mail-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
        at com.sun.mail.gimap.GmailStore.protocolConnect(GmailStore.java:92) ~[gimap-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]

Comment: Let's tackle the Gmail/XOAUTH2 in another thread. See answer below for workaround.

Answer (score 7):

There is currently a bug in the Contacts API where certain HTTP `User-Agent` strings, cause the 401 response to return as an HTML page instead of an XML response, and missing the `WWW-Authenticate` header that the `AuthenticationException` class is relying on. `GContacts-Java` is one of these special user agent strings. A workaround is to change the user agent of your client after you create it:

```
ContactsService service = new ContactsService(applicationName);
service.getRequestFactory().setHeader("User-Agent", applicationName);
```

This should eliminate the NPE, and allow the client library to automatically detect expired tokens and refresh them automatically.

Comment: Thank you Eric. I'll give it a try. And will open another question for the Gmail token issue.

Comment: Eric, it seemed like it fixed the issue for the Contacts API (GData) but now I also see that we get these new errors: <errors xmlns="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
 <error>
  <domain>GData</domain>
  <code>insufficientPermissions</code>
  <internalReason>Insufficient Permission</internalReason>
 </error>
</errors>   Any ideas why? Is it another sign of an expired token that is not handled automatically?

Comment: Here you go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26616591/gdata-insufficientpermissions

Comment: Eric, the NullPointerException "No authentication header information" issue seems to be back for Google Contacts API. We have not seen it for a long while after implementing your workaround but we see this error again in all our logs.

Comment: com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException.initFromAuthHeader(AuthenticationException.java:96) ~[gdata-core-1.0-1.47.1.jar:na]

Comment: @Alexey, we are encountering exactly what you were describing, and it's suddenly is happening after months of properly working.  The linked question was deleted.  Did you find a workaround or was there some other problem?  Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: The workaround is to refresh your token but this is annoying to catch NPE and handle it as a hack. Too bad Google keeps breaking their own gdata java library.

Comment: I've reached back out to the engineering team for more information.

Comment: same here. it fails on every call now. can anyone knowing how to handle this can place a GIST with workaround somewhere?

Comment: The problem started 2015-10-07 19:51:59,558 for my service http://gsyn.ch
I really don't know why Google didn't fix that problem. There should be more software out there using their Contacts API.
Here's my work-around to be called before the service is used:

 Long expiresIn = credential.getExpiresInSeconds();
 // check if token will expire in a minute
 if (credential.getAccessToken() == null || expiresIn != null && expiresIn <= 60)
 {
     boolean succ = credential.refreshToken();
     log.info("Refresh status {}", succ);
 }
 service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);

Comment: It's 2017 and the issue has not fixed yet.

Comment: So, does it mean can't simply use this service? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43050496/cant-get-the-list-of-accounts-using-google-contacts-api-oauth-2-0/43050984#43050984